# how to do a jQuery timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

using jQuery... how do I run a function and then run a second function every 2 minutes after.

eg:

function 1: runs once

function 2: runs every 2 minutes after function 1 has finished

Any help will be much appreciated.

C

Comment: Make sure you make clear what 'f1 has finished' really means. If you have any asynchronous (ajax) calls in f1, you might want to fire f2 in the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `delay()` function is not a replacement for javascript's `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. To run a function #1 once on page load and then function #2 every 2 minutes after:

```
function funcOne() { 
  // some javascript
  setInterval('funcTwo()', 1000*60*2);
};

function funcTwo() { 
  // some other javascript
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  funcOne();
});
```

Comment: Using string expressions in `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` is considered bad practice. The line `setInterval('funcTwo()', 1000*60*2);` could be rewritten as `setInterval(funcTwo, 1000*60*2);`

Comment: What if you need to pass arguments to the function? @Zanfa

Comment: setInterval(function() { funcTwo(arg1, arg2) }, 1000*60*2);

Comment: Then either use an anonymous function like AndreasAL showed, or rewrite the function to not use arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
function f2(){}
function f1(){
    ... some code ...
    setInterval(f2, 2000*60);
}
//From somewhere in your code, call f1
f1();
```

setInterval also returns a handle which can be used to cancel further calling of that function.

Comment: thanks @spicavigo. is setinterval better than using jQuery .delay()?

Comment: he meant after 2 minutes of the first call of the first function

Comment: It depends on the use case. I would use setInterval if my use case is as simple as the one you mentioned and those provided by third party like jQuery only if I am doing something complicated.

Comment: Thanks @Marwan. I changed the code to run after every 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Remember, you are using JQuery because it makes javascript more simple. **JQuery is a javascript library**, not a language, wich means you can perfectly use javascript functions on it.

For your problem, you only need to call, with the setTimeout, your second function, and put inside this function another `setTimeout(ms);`

Like this:

```
function f1(/*...*/){}
var t = setTimeout("f2()",2 * 60 * 1000);
```

And at the end of your `f2()` function you should include another setTimeout, in order to call that function every 2 minutes.

```
function f2(/*...*/){
    //...
    t = setTimeout("f2()",2 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

To cancel this callings to `f2()` is just as simple: `clearTimeout(t);`

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use setTimeout(). It is supposed to be less demanding on the browser, more processor efficient.

Here's what your functions should look like:

```
function f2(){
    t = setTimeout(f2, 2000 * 60);
    // code for f2
}

function f1(){
    // code for f1
    setTimeout(f2, 2000 * 60);
}
```

Then wherever it is you want the whole thing to start, call the first function:

```
var t;
f1();
```

You can stop the loop anytime:

```
clearTimeout(t);
```

Be sure to trigger setTimeout at the beginning of f2, so that it fires exactly every 2 minutes. Any code before 'setTimeout', taking 'x' time to process would result in the next f2 call firing after 2min+x.

Answer (score -2):

Heloo 
if i get you right then this is a solution

```
function func1()
{}

function func2()
{}

window.onload = function()
{
func1();

var flag_first_call_is_after_2=0;
var interv = setInterval(
function()
{
if(flag_first_call_is_after_2==0)
{
flag_first_call_is_after_2=1;
}
else
{
func2();
}
}
,120000
);
}
```